# L2S :Convert Sql query to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert this SQL query to LINQ but failed to do so..
any help is appreciated...

```
SELECT [t0].id,
   sum([t1].[total_Statements]) AS [value],
   sum( [t1].[totalpage] - [t1].[total_Statements]) AS [value2],
   sum( [t1].[total_bad]) AS [value3],
   [t0].[biller_id]
    FROM [dbo].[upload_t] AS [t0]
    left JOIN [dbo].[printer] AS [t1] ON 
    ((CONVERT(NVarChar,[t0].[id])) = [t1].bill])
    where (([t0].[biller_id] = 10) 
    group by [t0].[biller_id],[t0].id,[t0].[date] 
   ORDER BY [t0].[date] DESC
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = 
ctx.upload_t.Where(w1=>w1.biller_id==10)
.join(ctx.printer, t0=>t0.id.ToString(), t1=>t1.bill.ToString(),
(t0,t1) => new {t0.id, t0.biller_id, t1.total_statements, t1.total_page, t1.total_bad,t0.date})
.GroupBy(g1=>new {t0.biller_id,t0.id,t0.date)
.Select(s1=>new{
   s1.Key.id, 
   value=s1.Sum(s2=>s2.total_statements),
   value2=s1.Sum(s2=>s2.total_page-s2.total_statements),
   value3=s1.Sum(s2=>s2.total_bad),
   s1.Key.biller_id, s1.Key.date})
.OrderBy(o1=>o1.date)
```

if you can live with the extra date column ... if not, do another select afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could download a trial version of [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/). This will help you convert SQL queries to Linq queries, and in the process you might learn Linq aswell.

Comment: That's not a solution. Its an alternative. Should be a comment.

Comment: Yes. That's why i said your answer should be a comment.